# How to save a reactive dataTableOutput to csv

Tags: r, csv, shiny, reactive

I am looking for help to save a reactive table rendered with `renderDataTable()` in a shiny app **to a csv file**.

Basically the app consists of a data entry form that generates a bunch of reactive summary table for each id:

After some search I found this:
This shiny app works (from here https://localcoder.org/shiny-r-download-the-result-of-a-table

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)

ui <- fluidPage(
  # This one is linked by the id 'download'
  fluidRow(column(7,dataTableOutput('dto')))
)

server <- function(input,output){
  # Reactive expression with the data, in this case iris
  thedata <- reactive(iris)
  
  #the extensions parameter coupled with the options list does the trick  
  output$dto <- renderDataTable(thedata(), extensions = 'Buttons', 
                                options = list(dom = 'Bfrtip',
                                               buttons = c('copy', 'csv', 'excel', 'pdf', 'print'))
  )
}

runApp(list(ui=ui,server=server), launch.browser=TRUE) #now runs by default in the external browser.
```

This example shows want I want. The difference to my use case is that that the reactive table is rendered/created each time I change the id in a list of data entry form. Therefore the difference is that I have not a consistent dataframe like `iris` in the provided example.

**So my question is:**
Given the name of my reactive table is `my_irisreactive` how could I modify the code.

I have tried this:(does not work)

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)

ui <- fluidPage(
  # This one is linked by the id 'download'
  fluidRow(column(7,dataTableOutput('dto')))
)

server <- function(input,output){

  output$dto <- renderDataTable(myirisreactive(), extensions = 'Buttons', 
                                options = list(dom = 'Bfrtip',
                                               buttons = c('copy', 'csv', 'excel', 'pdf', 'print'))
  )
}

runApp(list(ui=ui,server=server), launch.browser=TRUE) #now runs by default in the external browser.
```

**Update:** The code that creates `my_irisreactive`.

```
my_irisreactive <- reactive({  
  
  #50 lines of code that do something

  my_irisreactive <- cbind(input$patientID, other_reactivetable)
  return(my_irisreactive)
  
})
```

This code is sourced with this:

```
  server = function(input, output, session) { 
    ## Server functions are divided by tab
   ## many sources
    source("./server/serverfunctions/server-functions-my_irisreactive.R", local = TRUE)
  })
```

Comment: Can you show us the code where you create `myirisreactive()`?

Comment: It depends on how you are creating `input$patientID`.  If it is created every time you call `my_irisreactive()`, it will not work as Shiny requires the input ID to be unique.

Comment: `input$patiendID` is already created. I cand see the `my_irisreactive()` table. If I change the list of entries I new `my_irisreactive()` is again created and I can see it. So the question is how can I download the actual appearing `my_irisreactive()` on the screen to a csv via `downloadhandler`.